# CSS Border irr behavior on colspan TD

Tags: css

I have a CSS problem regarding borders, the problem is adding borders around a td that has a colspan.

The table has properties:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
```

The CSS style:

```
.tdclass{
    background-color:#FDBCC1;
}

.tdclass td{
    border-top: 3px solid white;
}
```

The way it works is like this:

```
<tr class = "tdclass">
<td> ...
<td colspan="2"> ...
<td> ...
</tr>
```

What this CSS does is highlights certain rows and adds a white line that acts
as a fake row spacing. Adding borders to the `<tr>` element does not work, only
works on `<td>`.

Now this works fine on all the cells, except on the cell with the "colspan".
The problem is that it generates the border BUT it is not white, it is the same
color as the cell background which is defiend in ".tdclass". This problem seems
to happen only on the "colspan" `<td>` element.
So the effect looks as if the cell has shifted up from the row:

It likes this:

```
____-----____
```

Where that little bump is the `<td>` with "colspan" in. It looks like bump because
all other cells generate a white border while that generates a border that has
the same color as the `.tdclass` "background-color".

Any reason why? Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you assign the class in the td tag instead of the tr?  Is this occurring in different browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any content in your td with the colspan?

IE, Firefox, and Chrome render the following in three different ways:

```
<tr class = "tdclass">
 <td> blah</td>
 <td colspan="2"> </td>
 <td> blah</td>
</tr>
```

Chrome does what you expect. Firefox does what you describe. IE leaves off the border and does not extend the background color.

Try inserting a `&nbsp;` in your empty cells.

Comment: great thanks, that solves it, there is content but its dynamically generated and not always available

Comment: You may have to include a &nbsp; by default. Maybe you can do it in JS where if the table cell is empty it will drop one in.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<td>` a border directly, e.g. `css("border-top", "#808080 1px dotted")`